# js/jQuery How to assign check box value to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm using Eric Hynds jQuery MultiSelect Widget that is being populated from a javascript file. The issue is that either selection adds to both sides. Option 1-3 should only add to Main1-3, same for option/Main 4-6. Please see my fiddle of how it works and the issue http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/112/

I think it would be eaisiest to break it out something like

```
var lbl = $("#MDCselect").val();
        if (number1.checked) {...
             ('.holder').append...

var lbl2 = $("#ClinicalSelect").val();
            if (number2.checked) {...
                ('.holder2').append...
```

currently

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
        header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
        click: function (event, ui) {
            var number1 = $("#MDCselect").children(":checked").length,
                number2 = $("#Clinicalselect").children(":checked").length;

            if (ui.checked && ((number1 + number2 >= 5) || $(this).children(":checked").length >= 5)) {
                return false;
            }

            var lbl = ui.value;
            if (ui.checked) {
                var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="' + lbl.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[,\s]/g, '') + '">';
                $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function () {
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>' + ctrl + lbl + '</div>');
                });
            } else {
                $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function () {
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('#' + lbl.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[,\s]/g, '')).parent().remove();
                })
            }
        },
        selectedList: 5
    });
    $(".checkers").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).nextAll('.holder:eq(0)').find('div input').parent().remove();
        } else {
            var checkedOnes = $('#MDCselect').nextAll('.ui-multiselect-menu').find('ul li input:checked');
            $(".holder").html("");
            for (var i = 0; i < checkedOnes.length; i++) {
                var lbl = checkedOnes.eq(i).attr('value');
                var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="' + lbl.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[,\s]/g, '') + '">';
                $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function () {
                    $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>' + ctrl + lbl + '</div>');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't get what exactly you are trying to say

Comment: so in my fiddle ex: You check Main1 and Main4. If you check on value1 from the first dropdown, it should ONLY show under Main1 and NOT Main4. If you then check value4 from the 2nd dropdown, it should ONLY show under Main4 and NOT Main1. Please let me know if this is still not clear.

Comment: Only Values 1-3 should populate under Mains1-3. Only Values 4-6 should populate under Mains4-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I get what you want to do, try this and let me know if it is what you want, here is the fiddle if you want to try it http://jsfiddle.net/8xBcd/

I put the mains in a containing div, that way is easier to make selectors for the diferent mains. check the fiddle please.

```
<div id="main1-3" >
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="Main1" id="id1" class='checkers'/><label for="Main1"><b>Main1</b></label>
<div class="holder"></div>
</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" value="Main2" id="id2" class='checkers'><label for="Main2"><b> Main2</b></label>
<div class="holder"></div>
</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk3" value="Main3" id="id3" class='checkers'><label for="Main3"><b> Main3</b></label>
<div class="holder"></div>
</div>

<select id="MDCselect" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3, this space</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Values 1-3 should all be able to show under Main1. Values 1-3 should all be able to show under Main2 and Main3. Values 1-3 should under no circumstance show under Main4, 5, or 6. The .checker click function will also need to be worked to apply this.

Comment: The way it currently works(which is correct) is that if you select a value, it will only show under a Main IF that Main is checked. If Main is unchecked it then removes it below. If Main is then rechecked it will re-"pull" again and show. I simply need to seperate the current functionality to where Values 1-3 under no circumstance shows under Main4-6. etc

Comment: Is there a way to create my own external js URL to plug into jsfiddle? I'm having trouble implementing this in my project since the dropdowns are being populated from a js file.